# QuickSort on a Queue?

Tags: java

I got asked to do this :

But all the examples of quick sort use arrays? I have seen other post on here which say it is possible but dont really explain how? I already got an implementation of a queue "using a linked list" and the class.

Comment: Quicksort requires random access, which is not generally what queues are known for. Ask the assignment giver for clarification.

Comment: It is entirely possible to implement a queue that is backed by a random access collection. All you need to do is implement the required interface.

Comment: @Kayaman True that it's not really possible with the public methods that queues expose (add to tail / remove from head) but within the class the elements are stored as a linked list and its perfectly possible to quicksort that (perhaps not efficiently but it's only a learning exercise)

Comment: @Michael I'm not talking about the `Queue` interface, I'm talking about the concept of queues, which are `FIFO`. Of course you can implement things so it's possible, and like you said you can quicksort a `LinkedList` which is a `Queue`. It's not a very good learning exercise if you're supposed to do something really stupid.

Comment: @NimrodArgov you too. Just because you **can**, doesn't mean you **should**. A teacher giving an exercise like this isn't doing a favor for their students.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am going to ask if I am supposed to add methods which were not apart of the Queue interface to complete this problem.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't agree. There are real world examples of collections that were implemented with different mechanisms under the hood, in order to achieve certain characteristics, such as runtime complexity. The vector in Scala, for example is implemented using a tree. Are you going to claim it's wrong?

Comment: @NimrodArgov it's implemented using a **trie**, and there's a good reason for it. There is not a good reason for quicksorting a queue.

Comment: @Michael I do think that there is something objectively wrong in explicitly implementing ineffective data structures. In Java `LinkedList` gets `sort()` from `List`, because it's part of the interface (and it's not quicksort).

Comment: @Michael I wasn't even talking about `LinkedList`, you were. The assignment was talking about a FIFO queue, and that's not a suitable data structure for quicksort. You all started talking about different implementations and all that crap.

Comment: @Michael a queue by definition doesn't give enough information on whether it is even sortable or not. It just says that you can put things in one end and take things from the other. Priority queue tells you that you'll be getting sorted elements from it, but it's the queue sorting itself, not you. I can't believe you're defending the sorting of queues with such fervour, when I'm criticizing an apparently poorly worded assignment.

Comment: @Michael I'm not talking about anything related to you. I'm talking about the assignment, and you did not give the assignment. You can do whatever you want, I do not care if you quicksort linkedlists or create interfaces, this is not your assignment. There is something objectively wrong if you choose an inefficient sorting method when you know that it's inefficient.

Comment: @Michael the assignment specifies quicksort if you read the question. Quicksort and queue don't mix. I said this in the first comment, but for some reason you insist that it's a good idea to do exercises that use suboptimal algorithms. You're wrong here, I was just informing the OP to ask about the seemingly conflicting requirements, but you apparently are fighting for poor programming practices.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't know how I'm not getting through to you so [I just did the bloody thing](https://ideone.com/5naLP0) to prove you wrong.

Comment: @Michael you seem to think I'm somehow claiming that it's impossible. I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm saying it's stupid. Teaching students to write stupid code is also stupid. Do you understand? I can't believe I'm not getting through to you.

Comment: @Michael a true queue does not support random access. Just because we can implement queues that do have random access either efficiently (for example `ArrayBlockingQueue`) or inefficiently (e.g. `LinkedList`) does not mean that quicksort is suitable for queues in general.

Comment: @Kayaman The queue I posted does not support random access.

Comment: @Michael and therefore quicksort isn't a very good choice of algorithm. Also, your queue uses an `ArrayList` internally which does support random access, so your queue **does** support random access, as long as the internal implementation is known. So basically you're saying that "queues can be efficiently sorted with quicksort as long as it's internally implemented with a data structure that supports random access". Again, not something general to queues, but a particular feature of your particular implementation.

Comment: @Michael I don't understand why you insist on using lists when the question was about queues. You're bending the requirements to support your (ridiculous) notion that quicksorting queues is a normal thing. I'm talking about the general sense as described in the question, but you're doing your own implementations which have nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: @Michael but when you're in an educational context, you don't implement a queue with a list. Just like you don't implement a list with a map where the key is the index. Remember that the OP is a student. I wish you hadn't hijacked this question like this.

Comment: @Michael err, `ArrayList` was what I meant. With a linked list, most definitely (and that's linked list, not `LinkedList`). Basic student tasks, make a linked list, now make a doubly linked list etc., but you're considering this question from an entirely different context which isn't useful for the *student* i.e. OP.

Comment: @Kayaman We can sort a linked list using a quicksort. If your quibble is (and I'm honestly still not sure *what* your quibble is...) that quicksorting a linked list is inefficient (because random access is not O(1)), then it's *you* that's not considering it from a student's perspective.

Comment: @Michael of course we can sort a linked lsit using quicksort, there's just no reason why students should be taught to do that. It's hard enough to teach them how to do things *correctly*.

Comment: @Kayaman List implementations should abstract away the details of how they're implemented. Implementing a quicksort on a linked list should be no different from implementing it on an array or an array-based list. The goals here seems to be to learn about queues and sorting algorithms, not when and when not to use different types of lists. In that regard, the exercise serves its purpose perfectly well. The fact that you disagree with the way it's being taught is, frankly, irrelevant.

Comment: @Michael finally we agree on things. As list should abstract away implementation details, queue should also do that. Your solution was based on implementation details, which means you failed in the abstraction part. Thank you for finally understanding.

Answer (score 1):

A true quick sort requires the ability to swap elements, something not easily done with a queue, probably requiring moving portions of the queue to temp queues in order to "swap" elements.

A quick sort like algorithm can be used for FIFO type containers like a queue. The first element could be used as the pivot, then 3 queues are created, one for elements < pivot, one for elements == pivot, one for elements > pivot. Recursion is used for the two queues with elements != pivot, then the 3 queues are "concatenated" to form a sorted queue. Other elements could be used for the pivot, but this would involve cycling through the queue to access the target element for a pivot.

Comment - merge sort makes more sense when restricted to FIFO containers. Merge sort can also be used when restricted to LIFO (stack) like containers (a minimum of 3 LIFO containers are needed (complicated if using polyphase based merge sort), 4 LIFO containers is more straight forward).

Comment: As I've mentioned in the comments on the question, if you're sorting from *within* the queue class and not from *outside* the queue then you're not restricted to only head/tail operations. From within the class, you could quite easily quicksort the underlying data structure (whether it be an array, a list, or whatever else).

Comment: @Michael - but that would be a quick sort on the underlying data structure, not a quick sort on a queue.

Comment: In the question (edited now), the exercise didn't say the sort has to be *on* the queue. The wording could be better, but the only reasonable interpretation is "create a Queue class that ... can sort ... based on last name or age."

Comment: @Michael - OK, but the title is "Quicksort  on a Queue?", which led me to believe the assignment is to implement a quicksort using a queue (FIFO) interface.